# Meaning of 万々が一

Tags: grammar, particle-が

> しかし、**万々が一**ポッターたちが関わっていたにせよ、あの連中が自分たちの近くにやってくるはずがない。
>   However, ??? even if it did concern the Potters, there was no reason to expect that that lot would turn up in their own neighbourhood.

I haven't the faintest idea what 万々が一 means in this sentence. I understand that 万々 means 'very much', but why would an adverb take が (besides which, I can't see any way to fit 'very much' into the sentence)? There also appears to be two subjects in 万々が一ポッターたちが関わっていた.

I don't know if 一 is part of the same problem or whether it somehow prefixes ポッターたち。Either way, I don't understand this part either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%87%E4%B8%87%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%80) it's used to strengthen `万が一`, which is a set phrase meaning "if by any chance; in the unlikely event that".